# What is the maximum value of unsigned DECIMAL(M, D) column?

Tags: mysql, decimal, unsigned

I found a `DECIMAL(5, 2)` column supports a range of `-999.99` to `999.99` in [12.22.2 DECIMAL Data Type Characteristics](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html).

When the column is defined as *UNSIGNED*, what is the maximum value that the column supports? Is it still `999.99`?

Comment: An easy one to test surely? Is there a question behind the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably took less time than your typing the question. Like P.Salmon said, there really should be something more deep behind this.

```
create table td (d decimal(5,2) unsigned);
insert td values(999.99);
-- Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
insert td values(1000);
-- ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'd' at row 1
```